# Why does Fastscripts work with this but Platypus doesn't

Tags: macos, shell, macos-catalina, platypus

Mac running Catalina. This code

```
#!/bin/bash

pbpaste|pbcopy
pbpaste>/tmp/tmp$$
open -W -a macvim /tmp/tmp$$
while [ `ps -A|grep MacVim|wc -l` -gt 1 ]
do sleep 1
done
cat /tmp/tmp$$|pbcopy
rm -f /tmp/tmp$$
```

is intended to plain-text the paste buffer then call up a terminal running macvim so I can use vi with less faff then put the result back in the clipboard. Its a way to speed-up editing when using various tools other tools and I just want to edit a section with vi.

I works well when called from Fastscripts or just plain execution but it won't work when I use Platypus to build a menubar app so its one fast click to use it - or rather, it works *sometimes*.  Sometimes it hangs because it cannot connect input to the window in which macvim runs.  I have to kill it from Activity Monitor to regain any control of input to other windows such as terminal. I've tried connecting stdin in the "open" command but still only works sometimes. And it shouldn't be standin anyway.

How is Fastscripts launching it and how can I do the same inside the script ?

I'd like very much to be able to launch it with a single click from the menubar but I don't know how to. I can build the platypus app if I know what to put in the shell script.

Thanks

andy

Comment: sorry, accidentally chopped off the bang line - running in bash

Comment: Not sure about the first two lines... those begining `pbpaste`. Firstly, it seems like a potential deadlock to write to the clipboard whilst reading it and secondly because the next suggestion seems more succinct. Why not replace them with `pbpaste > /tmp/tmp$$`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, BUT .. This is a recognised way to make the clipboard plain text and there is no problem at all with those lines - its documented widely in forums like this one. Besides which it works perfectly as a shell script when used alone or when started by FastScripts.  Its only when used as a script called by Platypus that it doesn't work.  Since the macvim will start in the background the lines after that are protected from executing by the while.  What isn't working is something to do with how input gets inherited by apps and sub shells etc.

Comment: I don't get that. Surely if the `pbcopy` makes the plain text conversion it would have done that when you copied. And if the `pbpaste` is responsible for the plain text conversion it will do that more simply in my version? Also, you say the input isn't inherited but I don't see any input to anything... which input to what from where do you mean please?

Comment: @Mark Setchell: I think I may be getting you now and you may be right.  I can't remember where I read the trick of pbpaste|pbcopy to plain-text the clipboard - I've been using it for ages with no problems - it was on a similar forum to this. pbpaste>/tmp/tmp$$ should do the same job with less code. But that still doesn't explain things.  As I understand it the only command that completes but leaves something running in the background is the "open" - the others are just a "list" - am I wrong on that ?

Comment: The `open` has the `-W` flag which means the script waits till `MacVIM` exits - so I don't know why you have a `while` loop either.

Comment: Try making a dummy file with `ls > XXX` in your Terminal and then running 'open -W -a macvim XXX` and see if the command exits before or as you close `MacVIM`.

Comment: The -W was a later addition to try and make it work (it doesn't seem to make a difference because it only waits for the open, not the macvim to finish). The while was to wait for the macvim to finish because the content to copy back to the past buffer isn't available until it has done.

Comment: Mark - As for a dummy file with XXX - that's exactly what it does, except its /tmp/tmp$$ instead of 'XXX'  And the while is fine - it waits for the macvim to finish and works fine. It seems to behave as if the pbpaste and pbcopy are operating in the background and sometimes not completing in time (though the macvim has never failed to pick up the right content from /tmp/tmp$$.

Comment: GOT IT!!!!! I noticed that the larger the quantity of text in the clipboard the more likely it is to fail.  I reckon by putting pbpaste and pbcopy in a pipe the code is reading and writing from/to the same "file" at the same time. If not all the content of the clipboard has gone down the pipe from pbpaste before pbcopy starts writing ... not tried modifiying it yet but convinced this is what the problem is. Thanks Mark.

Comment: nope, same problems